# How to make train data observation similar to my test data in R ? My observations are less than it supposed to be

Tags: r

I would like to make my train data and test data with equal observation right now my train dataset has fewer observations than test data. Unable to figure out which code do I need to use. I have tried merge, subset, all types of joints

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tidymodels package:

```
library(tidymodels)
#lets assume your dataset is called: dat
dat_split  <- initial_split(dat, prop = 3/4) #with prop argument you decide how big should train set be proportionally 

train_dat <- training(dat_split)
test_dat <- testing(dat_split)
```